# Converting a UIAlertView text into a UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel, uialertview

Kind of a weird question, I know but i'm wondering how it would be possible to transfer information from a UIAlertView to a UILabel. I've been trying myself for the past few hours with no luck. I'm playing around with some pre-existing code so it is kind of hard for me to follow my steps back as to how they came to populate the UIAlertView, however I'm thinking it'll be easier to display the body text on the Label rather than type over the code. It is also using a REST API which is how the data is being generated (generates 4 different instances depending on political alignment).

Here is a snippet of the UIAlertViewCode

```
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:result options:0 error:0];

[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Response" message:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] 
delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
```

will i require any other pieces of code??

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the message in a variable then reuse it:

```
//message
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:result options:0 error:0];
NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//UIAlert
[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Response" message:message 
delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];

//UILabel
yourLabel.text = message;
```